# training two networks simultaneously in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Imagine `x_1` and `x_2` are two inputs of a neural network and `y_1` and `y_2` are the outputs. Then `y_1` and `y_2` should be concatenated and passed into a second network. The output of the second network is a single binary label `z={0,1}`. I have the matrix `X=[x_1;x_2;...;x_2n]` (input of the first network) and labels `Z = [z_1;z_2;...;z_n]` (output of the second network).

How can I setup this structure in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two models called `model1` and `model2`, and your inputs `x_1` and `x_2` are the tensor inputs to `model1`:

```
x = [x_1, x_2]
y = model1(x)
y = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(y)
z = model2(y)
combined_model = tf.keras.Model(x, z)
```